# rails 3 + devise, probably pretty easy: how link a (app-specific) Customer object to a (devise-created) User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Our app (before authentication) has Customers and Widgets. As you'd expect each customer has a single record in the Customers table, and we don't want customers to get into each other's accounts.

I was able to get devise for rails installed and working fine. (The most helpful tutorials IMO were http://presentations.royvandewater.com/authentication-with-devise.html and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise )

our root page on our site (Home#index) simply displays the register or sign-in links.

if user signs in we want to take them to the CustomerSController show method for THEIR account...

so I need to do three things, none of which I see how to do with Devise:

a) when a User registers, and User record is created, also create a 
new blank Customer record   (I know 
how to create a Customer.new, I just
don't see where to 'put' that code)

b) associate that brand new Customer 
record with their User
record (1 to 1) -- should I put
the customer.id in users or the
other way around?

c) when they sign in, direct them to

```
customers/[theUser.customer.id]
```

(or something like that)

Comment: I'm not sure on the business of your system however why don't you run devise on the Customer model and identify that, instead of having an extra model for each customer.

Comment: because nowhere in any tutorial or docs did I see that you could do that, or how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a & b)
You have to use after create hook (something like this):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer
  after_create :assign_customer

protected
  def assign_customer
    customer.create
  end
end
```

c) And then in registrations controller add this:

```
 def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   customer_path(resource.customer)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite devise controller, like `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` and put there everything you want, including redirect and others